Spring boot @ConfigurationProperties not binding every property
I'm trying to figure out why some properties are not bound using @ConfigurationProperties.
I have a project using an external library which uses spring-kafka to set up a Kafka consumer.
This library has a KafkaProperties record
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "kafka")
public record KafkaProperties(
        String securityProtocol,
        String bootstrapServers,
        String groupId,
        String topic,
        String offset,
        String sslTruststoreLocation,
        String sslTruststorePassword,
        String messageKeyFilter) {
}

It also has a KafkaConfig class
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(KafkaProperties.class)
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Payload> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Payload> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory(kafkaProperties));
        if (StringUtils.hasText(kafkaProperties.messageKeyFilter())) {
            factory.setRecordFilterStrategy(consumerRecord -> !consumerRecord.key().contains(kafkaProperties.messageKeyFilter()));
        }
        return factory;
    }

    private ConsumerFactory<String, Payload> consumerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        Map<String, Object> props = createConsumerConfig(kafkaProperties);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(), getPayloadJsonDeserializer());
    }

    private Map<String, Object> createConsumerConfig(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.bootstrapServers());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.groupId());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.offset());

        if("SSL".equals(kafkaProperties.securityProtocol())) {
            props.put("security.protocol", kafkaProperties.securityProtocol());
            props.put("ssl.truststore.location", kafkaProperties.sslTruststoreLocation());
            props.put("ssl.truststore.password", kafkaProperties.sslTruststorePassword());
        }
        return props;
    }

    private static JsonDeserializer<Payload> getPayloadJsonDeserializer() {
        JsonDeserializer<Payload> deserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>(Payload.class);
        deserializer.trustedPackages("kafka.listener.model.*");
        return deserializer;
    }
} 

Now in the project implementing this library, I have the application.yml which contains these properties
kafka:
  bootstrap-servers: ${KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER}
  group-id: ${KAFKA_GROUP_ID}
  topic: ${KAFKA_TOPIC}
  offset: ${KAFKA_OFFSET}
  security-protocol: ${SECURITY_PROTOCOL}
  ssl-truststore-location: ${SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION}
  ssl-truststore-password: ${SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD}
  message-key-filter: ${MESSAGE_KEY_FILTER}

In its deployment.yml I have set up these environment variables (and I also have the truststore password in a secret).
  env:
    - name: SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION
      value: "/mypath/kafka-truststore.jks"
    - name: KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER
      value: "my-bootstratp-server"
    - name: KAFKA_TOPIC
      value: "testtopic"
    - name: KAFKA_GROUP_ID
      value: "tesgroup"
    - name: KAFKA_OFFSET
      value: "earliest"
    - name: MESSAGE_KEY_FILTER
      value: "testkey"
    - name: SECURITY_PROTOCOL
      value: "SSL"

I deploy the image to an Openshift environment and it's giving me an exception.
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory]: Factory method 'kafkaListenerContainerFactory' threw exception with message: null
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:643)
... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putAll(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.<init>(Unknown Source)

When remote debugging the pod and putting a breakpoint on kafkaListenerContainerFactory bean, I can see that only some properties were bound.
kafkaProperties:
groupId=tesgroup
topic=testtopic
offset=earliest
securityProtocol=null
bootstrapServers=null
sslTruststoreLocation=null
sslTruststorePassword=null
messageKeyFilter=null

I tried to run a container locally with the same environment variables and the consumer is properly set up and no exception is encountered.
I also tried to use Spring Environment instead of a KafkaProperties record and all environment variables were correctly picked up when using them in the KafkaConfig class.
And I don't see anything wrong with the properties name in the application.yml that could make the binding not work.
A little help would be very welcomed.
Thank you!

We cannot see that picture. Please, copy/paste it as a text.

@ArtemBilan updated thanks

Apparently those ENV vars are not bound somehow in your pods. Nothing to do with Spring or Apache Kafka itself.

What version of spring-boot are you using?. It looks like kebab case properties from YAML are not initialized to their respective camel case variables but lower case ones initialized.

@Imran Thanks for your comment. I'm using spring boot 3.1.11. But then group-id/groupId is correctly initialized.

I picked up again the project and got it to work with KafkaProperties record. I didn't bring any changes so I'm not sure why it's working as it should now.
